# Unable to install yesod-bin

Tags: linux, haskell, ghc, yesod

I'm updating my yesod framework to the latest yesod 1.2 version.  I've installed yesod-platform (painfully....had to manually delete old dependency....cabal hell), now I need to install yesod-bin and it should be done.  However, after `sudo cabal install yesod-bin` I'm getting the following error.

```
Building yesod-bin-1.2.0...
Preprocessing executable 'yesod-ld-wrapper' for yesod-bin-1.2.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ghcwrapper.hs, dist/build/yesod-ld-wrapper/yesod-ld-wrapper-tmp/Main.o )
Linking dist/build/yesod-ld-wrapper/yesod-ld-wrapper ...
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHStar-0.4.0.1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSoptparse-applicative-0.5.2.1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSghc-paths-0.1.0.9
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSfsnotify-0.0.6
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHShinotify-0.3.5
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Failed to install yesod-bin-1.2.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
yesod-bin-1.2.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

According to [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3794), I feel it may have something to do with privileges I'm not sure.

EDIT: So I only found the following two libraries.

```
/usr/lib/haskell-packages/ghc/lib/tar-0.3.2.0/ghc-7.4.1/libHStar-0.3.2.0.a
/usr/lib/haskell-packages/ghc/lib/ghc-paths-0.1.0.8/ghc-7.4.1/libHSghc-paths-0.1.0.8.a
```

I'm trying to update `libghc-tar-dev` to the newest version 0.4.0.1.  However, 0.3.2.0 is the newest version on `apt-get` what are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'd check to see if you have the libraries libHStar, libHSoptparse-applicative, libHSghc-paths, libHSfsnotify and libHShinotify. If you installed the haskell platform using your distro's package manager, I suspect you'll find those libraries in `/usr/local/lib/ghc-*.*.*/`. For example, you might search for the first library using this command:

```
sudo find /usr/local/lib -name 'libHStar*'
```

If you don't have those libraries, then I think you can get them by using your distro's package manager to install the following:

- libghc-tar-dev
- libghc-optparse-applicative-dev
- libghc-ghc-paths-dev
- libghc-fsnotify-dev
- libghc-hinotify-dev

If you already have those libraries, then you could adapt the fix suggested in your link:

```
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/lib/ghc-*/libHS*
```

---

UPDATE:

The standard recommendation seems to be that you should always use your linux distro's package manager to install stuff, rather than using the `cabal` command directly. And if a package you want isn't available yet on your distro, request it. This approach is the safest, because all of the dependencies have been sorted out for you. The disadvantage is that you won't usually have the latest release. I see that there is a `yesod` package on Ubuntu. I have no idea if it contains yesod-bin (I'm not familiar with yesod), but if it does, that's the safest approach. The downside is that you will probably have to wipe out your cabal library and start from scratch (re-install haskell-platform, then yesod).

Another option, which seems to be the road you're on, is to use your package manager to install the haskell-platform, but after that use the `cabal` command to install any haskell-y stuff. You'll still use your package manager to install things that can't be installed using cabal (e.g., non-haskell stuff). If you do this, you can avoid a lot of cabal hell by never running cabal as root, and never letting your package manager do anything that can be done using cabal. The main disadvantage of this approach is that you have to deal with library dependencies yourself, as you've discovered. If you want to continue down this road, you might be able to get everything you need by switching to some development/test build for Ubuntu. Or you may have to get the correct versions of the libraries you need and manually install them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply the libs are not in that folder, I tried installing the libs using `apt-get`. However, I could only install `libghc-tar-dev` and `libghc-hinotify-dev`, and when I re-installed `yesod-bin` the error remain the same no change. Maybe it's in different folder?  Any suggestions on how to search for it?

Comment: You could find out for sure if a file is on your system using, for example, `sudo find /usr/local/lib -name 'libHStar*'`.

Comment: So I've got only two out of the five libraries needed, and the two are not the correct version, I'm finding it hard to get the libraries as they are not on `apt-get` for ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I've successfully installed `libghc-tar-dev-0.4.0.1`, and I've changed `HStar-0.4.0.1.o` and `libHStar-0.4.0.1.a` into `chmod 777`.  Yet when installing it still can't find `-lHStar`.  I'm thinking maybe the system doesn't know which directory to look for the libraries?

Comment: In the end of the day I wiped out ~/.ghc re-installed everything and it worked!  Thanks a lot for you time!